# How to animate first element of array instead of lasts by vue (animate.css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-directives

I have an array which has been updated by time, but `animate.css` always animate last element of array when array change.

```
<template>

<div class="">


    <div v-for="(device,index) in value" :key="index">
      <div v-if="device.hasOwnProperty('timeIn')" class="row" >
        <transition  :duration = "700" type="animation" enter-active-class="bounceInLeft" leave-active-class="bounceInRight" appear mode="out-in" key="1">
            <app-user-detected  :userDetected="device" ></app-user-detected key="1">
        </transition>

       </div>
        <div v-if="device.hasOwnProperty('timeOut')" class="out row" :key="3">
        <transition :duration = "400" type="animation" enter-active-class="fadeIn" leave-active-class="fadeOut" appear mode="out-in">
            <app-user-detail :userDetail="device"></app-user-detail>
        </transition>
        </div>


   </div>

</div>
</template>
```

Comment: value is an array,

Comment: value.unshift=data; // data always is being added to first index of array, but when Vue render, it always animate last index of array